# techniques to connect two tables in a sqlite database

Tags: database, sqlite

Im working on a project to save information of houses and members in it. the house table will store information of each house. (address, area of land, electraty......ect). and each house is givan a house number.  the members table will store information of all the members. (name, b'day, ..... ect).

now in the program when the user enter a house number the program will give the information of the house. now I need it to filter the members of the specific house and display their  informations too.

can someone point out me some technique to do this.

appreciate eny help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a JOIN between your two tables. You can find more information here : http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqljoin.php

Let's say your table `houses` has these info :

```
id | address | town | country | stairs | etc.
```

And the table `members` has these info :

```
id | name | sex | house_id
```

Where `house_id` is a foreign key linked to the id of the table `houses`

You SQL would look like this :

```
SELECT members.*, houses.* FROM members
LEFT JOIN houses ON houses.id = members.house_id
```

This would return every members from your table `members` with the info or their corresponding house.

Comment: I highly appriciate your answer. its easy to understand. many thanks. (accepted as the answer too)